# How do I generate a table's DDL programmatically in SqlServer?

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to generate a DDL of a table in SQL Server using Python. I tried to run the statement: `show create table schema.table` which didn't work. So I explored online for some help and found out that we can run the proc: `sp_help` as `exec sp_help schema.tablename`. One of the reason I am trying to generate the DDL is to get the DDL and create them in my target DB, (it is in snowflake & I am writing code to create the tables as well) get the PRIMARY & UNIQUE KEYS from the table and use them in my code (some requriement).

When I run the show create table as below, I get syntax error as below:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=servername;"
                      "Database=dbname;"
                      "uid=user;pwd=pwd")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('show create table dbname.tablename')
```

Error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'tablename'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

So I ran sp_help in the Sql Server management studio as below:

```
exec sp_help 'dbo.tablename';
```

The result:

[image]

In the image the proc: sp_help returns lot of data and column names are present in the second table of the result & the key constraints are present in the last table of the result.

All of this result is found in Sql Server Studio. So I ran the proc in python as below:

```
>>> import pymssql
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(host='Server\\Server',user='user', password='pwd',database='dbname')
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("exec sp_help 'dbo.tablename'")
```

But if I iterate the result from cursor as below:

```
>>> for r in cursor:
...     print(r)
...
```

I only see the first table in the result:

```
('tablename', 'dbo', 'user table', datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 27, 9, 51, 11, 213000))
```

This result is the first table from the result in the image given above.

The loop doesn't print other details that are shown from the image and I don't understand how can I implement loop properly to print/access the other data that was shown in the image above.
Is there anyway I can get the DDL from SQL Server in Python ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: a cursor only read row in a dataset. Before the cursor you need to have a loop over the multiple datasets of the component.

Answer (score 0):

In fact a procedure in SQL Sever can return more than one dataset.
You have to check :

1. the capability of your language to manage more than one dataset while executing a procedure (some languages are not able to !)
2. to do a loop over the multiple datasets